# Forcibly expire AWT token in Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to understand the DocuSign API C# QuickStart. I would like to follow the AWT token workflow, but I already authenticated my app an hour ago. So now, the AccessToken is saved somewhere for the next 7 hours. Is there a way to forcibly expire the existing token, so I can walk through the AWT calls - how they are called, how the tokens are received, saved etc.

Comment: I discovered a workaround - in EgController/CheckToken, you can set bufferMin to -3600 to force authentication. Not sure if this is advisable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manish, not sure what AWT is. We support OAuth ACG access token valid for 8h and JWT token valid for 1h. Setting bufferMin to -3600 will just force your app to request a new token, which in your case should allow you to follow the code logic

Comment: Thanks @IvanD, for your patience. While this workaround helps to understand the logic, I just found that it also breaks the app. This is because the checkToken() method is called at the start of the EgController/Get() action method. This means that when the app is redirected to "/" after authentication, it will again find the token expired. So, you have to reset bufferMin to 60 (or a positive value) for the app to work.

Comment: I thought the OAuth and JWT tokens were the same? Just different methods to get the token. Are they not?

Comment: They are completely different authentication types. You can read more in our guide - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/